# In-app share to instagram stories, not working on Android 11 and up

Tags: android, instagram-story

Implemented sharing of in-app content as sticker to Instagram stories as how it is implemented on official documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram/sharing-to-stories/, which is using intents and passing the data on what to share into it. It works fine with Android 10 and below, but when tried to test it on Android 11 and up, it stops working.

Answer (score 3):

For Android 11, That the App wanting to use the intent to do some actions needs to declare the query target in AndroidManifest.

So for sharing story to IG. You can add this query in AndroidManifest:

```
 <queries>

    <intent>
        <action android:name="com.instagram.share.ADD_TO_STORY" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent>

</queries>
```

Ref: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/package-visibility?hl=zh-cn#intent-signature